# vueJS mixin trigger multiple times in laravel 5.7

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5, vue.js

I am new in Vue jS [version 2]. There are 3 component in my page. I want to use a axios get data available in all pages. I have done as follows in my `app.js`

```
const router = new VueRouter({mode: 'history', routes });
Vue.mixin({
data: function () {
        return {
          pocketLanguages: [],

        }
    },
mounted() {
       var app = this;
       axios.get("/get-lang")
            .then(function (response) {
                app.pocketLanguages = response.data.pocketLanguages;
        })
    }
})

const app = new Vue({ 
    router,
}).$mount('#app');
```

and using this `pocketLanguages` in a component like

`{{ pocketLanguages.login_info }}` this. Its working fine but My Issue is `axios.get('')` triggering 4 times when page load [in console]

[image]

Now how can I trigger this only once or anything alternative suggestion will be appreciated to do this if explain with example [As I am new in Vue]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally problem solved

In `resources/js/components/LoginComponent.vue` file

```
<script>
import translator from '../translation';

export default {
    mixins:[translator],
    beforeCreate: function() {
        document.body.className = 'login-list-body';
    },
.....

mounted() {
        this.langTrans();
    }
```

and my `translation.js` file at `/resources/js`

```
export default {
 data: function() {
  return {
    pocketLanguages: []
  };
},
methods: {
langTrans: function() {
    var self = this;
    axios.get('/get-lang')
              .then(function (response) {
                  self.pocketLanguages = response.data.pocketLanguages;
              }); 
   }

  }
};
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using a [global mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#Global-Mixin), which means that every component in your app is going to make that axios `get` call when it's mounted. Since your page has several components in it, no wonder the call is being made several times. What you need to do here is either:

1. Create a normal mixin and only use it in the master/container/page component in every route that actually needs to fetch the data by providing the option `mixins: [yourMixinsName]`. That component can then share the data with the other components in the page.
2. If your data is common between pages then it's better to use a global store such as [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) to simplify state management.

**On a side note**: It is usually better to handle your data initialization in the `created` hook. Handling it in the `mounted` hook can lead to some pitfalls that include repeated calls, among other things, due to parent/child lifecycle hooks execution order. Please refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@brockreece/vue-parent-and-child-lifecycle-hooks-5d6236bd561f) for more information on the subject.

Comment: Would you plz provide a example how can I add mixin with each route?

Comment: Simply create a mixin object as seen in [these basic examples](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins#Option-Merging). Then provide it in the `mixins` option of the component that needs to fetch and populate the data in every route.